# Getting a list of unique hash key values from dynamodb using boto

Tags: boto, amazon-dynamodb

I want to get a list of unique hash key values for a dynamodb table. The only way that I know to do it currently is to scan the entire table and then iterate over the scan. What is the better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rs = list(table.scan(range__eq="rangevalue"))
for i in rs:
    print i['primarykey']
```

should do the trick. I'd love to hear cheaper ways to do the same thing.