# DynamoDB: Getting only most recent items of all unique hash keys

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

Given a DynamoDB table with a partition key `id` and sort key `date_epoch`.

I'll have items like this:

```
id  |  date_epoch
-----------------
1   |  1535961978
2   |  1535961996
1   |  1535962033
2   |  1535962055
3   |  1535962064
5   |  1535962073
1   |  1535962080
2   |  1535962085
```

For each given unique `id`, I only want its most recent item. So from this sample data, I only want the following results:

```
id  |  date_epoch
-----------------
3   |  1535962064
5   |  1535962073
1   |  1535962080
2   |  1535962085
```

I can figure out how to do this with very ugly code. I've gotten each unique `id`, then iterated over each individual `id` and gotten only the most recent item `.withScanIndexForward(false)` and `.withMaxResultSize(1)` (as shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438715/getting-a-list-of-unique-hash-key-values-from-dynamodb-using-boto) and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46541660/1478636)), but it seems like there must be a better way to do this.

Can we set a scan filter to limit the max items or something else I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but here it goes: No -  you can’t get the answer you are looking for with a scan. There is no way to craft a filter and even if there were, you’d still be paying for the full price of a scan (though you’d be saving on network bandwidth).

Your options are:

1. Use the technique you are using: get the unique Ids and then iterate and query with limit 1
2. Use two tables: one to hold the historical values and one to hold the most recent value for each item

Note that in the second example there are some caveats: you have to be tolerant of eventual consistency; and you must not update any of the items more than 1000 times per second (though the practical limit is realistically lower - maybe 6-700)

Comment: Appreciate the candor, glad I hadn't overlooked something in my solution